# Missing spaces/tabulations in JTextPane with HTML content

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane, pre

I have two different **JTextPanes**, the first one is a log where different **threads** send messages. There are saved sessions in **html** files, these files are used as the content of the second **JTextPane** when the user loads them. Both of the JTextPanes have **html** content type.

At the first JTextPane I insert the new lines directly into the `StyledDocument` with the `insertString()` method.
Everything is fine all spaces and tabulations are correct (before and after the `"OFFLINE"` tag):
[image]

Here is a picture about a part of the **html** file from NotePad++, with Show All Characters function:
[image]

The tabulations and the spaces are still there.

However, when I load back this file, and pass it to the second JTextPane it looks like this:
[image]

Tabulations and spaces are gone. I have tried using `&nbsp` instead of simple spaces but the result is the same.

Second JTextPane's code:

```
    //settings
    eventLogHistory = new JTextPane();
    eventLogHistory.setEditable(false);
    eventLogHistory.setName("eventLogHistory");
    eventLogHistory.setContentType("text/html");
```

Code doing the loading:

```
File f=new File(directory+"eventlog.html");
if(f.exists()) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
    String strtmp=new String();

    strtmp=scan.nextLine();
    strbld.append(strtmp+"\n");

    while(scan.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        strtmp=scan.nextLine();
        strbld.append(strtmp+"\n");
    }
    scan.close();

    getEventLogHistory().setText(strbld.toString());            
}
```

If I open the **html** file with Mozzila the tabulations and spaces are gone as well.

*How can this be solved, what do I miss here?*

**Update**
As it can be seen in [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson)'s answer I missed `<pre>` tags, thank you for the useful information. However these tags break the line and remove all style from the wrapped text. The following MCVE and sample input imitates the issue.

**So the new question is: how can I avoid the previously described behaviour of the `<pre>` tag?**

**MCVE**:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

public class TextPaneWithHTML
{
    public TextPaneWithHTML()
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTextPane with HTML content");

        final JTextPane eventLogHistory = new JTextPane();
        eventLogHistory.setEditable(false);
        eventLogHistory.setName("eventLogHistory");
        eventLogHistory.setContentType("text/html");
        eventLogHistory.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        JScrollPane messageTextScrollPane= new JScrollPane( eventLogHistory );
        messageTextScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        DefaultCaret caretMessageText = (DefaultCaret)eventLogHistory.getCaret();
        caretMessageText.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);

        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

        JButton loadButton = new JButton("Load content");
        loadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                StringBuilder strbld=new StringBuilder();

                int returnval=fc.showOpenDialog(frame);

                if (returnval == 0) 
                {                   
                    File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    try 
                    {
                        if(f.exists()) 
                        {
                            Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
                            String strtmp=new String();

                            while(scan.hasNextLine()) 
                            {
                                strtmp=scan.nextLine();
                                strbld.append(strtmp+System.getProperty("line.separator"));

                            }
                            scan.close();

                            eventLogHistory.setText(strbld.toString());         
                        }           
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }   
        });



        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
        frame.setSize(1200, 700);
        frame.getContentPane().add(messageTextScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(loadButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TextPaneWithHTML();
    }

}
```

**Test input, copy this into a txt file and save as html**:

```
<html>
 <head> 
 <style type="text/css"> 
.red{ color:#ff0000; }.blue{ color:#0000ff; }.green{ color:#33ff33; }.CLIgreen{ color:#02f002; }.khaki{ color:#8f8fff; }.white{ color:#ffffff; }.yellow{ color:#ffff00; }.pink{ color:#ff00ff; }.grey{ color:#d3d3d3; }.orange{ color:#ffc800; }p{ font-family: arial; font-size: 10; font-weight: bold; margin:0; } 
pre {
display:inline
}
 </style> 
 </head> 
<body>

<p><font class="white">[2014.11.17., 12:38:10]:  </font><font class="khaki">[TN-11111111]  [11111111]:  [cp1]   </font><font class="grey"><pre>OFFLINE          </pre></font><font class="white">  ----  </font><font class="green">SLAVE</font><font class="blue"></font></p>
<p><font class="white">[2014.11.17., 12:38:10]:  </font><font class="khaki">[TN-11111111]  [11111111]:  [cp2]   </font><font class="grey">OFFLINE          </font><font class="white">  ----  </font><font class="blue">MASTER</font>      
</p>
<p><font class="white">[2014.11.17., 12:38:10]:  </font><font class="khaki">[TN-11111111]  [11111111]:  [Clock] </font><font class="grey">OFFLINE          </font><font class="white">  ----  </font><font class="green">LOCKED</font><font class="blue"></font></p>
<p><font class="white">[2014.11.17., 12:38:10]:  </font><font class="khaki">[TN-11111112]  [11111112]:  [cp3]   </font><font class="grey">OFFLINE          </font><font class="white">  ----  </font><font class="green">SLAVE</font><font class="blue"></font></p>
<p><font class="white">[2014.11.17., 12:38:10]:  </font><font class="khaki">[TN-11111112]  [11111112]:  [cp4]   </font><font class="grey">OFFLINE          </font><font class="white">  ----  </font><font class="yellow">PASSIVE</font><font class="blue"></font></p>
<p><font class="white">[2014.11.17., 12:38:10]:  </font><font class="khaki">[TN-11111112]  [11111112]:  [cp2]   </font><font class="grey">OFFLINE          </font><font class="white">  ----  </font><font class="blue">MASTER</font>      
</p>
<p><font class="white">[2014.11.17., 12:38:10]:  </font><font class="khaki">[TN-11111112]  [11111112]:  [cp1]   </font><font class="grey">OFFLINE          </font><font class="white">  ----  </font><font class="blue">MASTER</font>      
</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

The `<pre>` tags are applied only for the first row and the line breaks at both `<pre>` and `</pre>`.

Comment: `strbld.append(strtmp+"\n");`  Re that `\n` - instead use `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

Comment: I changed to this `System.getProperty("line.separator")` but the `pre` tags still remove the style and add additional new lines.

Comment: Huh..  Maybe post an post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that fails for you, with a few lines of hard coded data.

Comment: Okey. I post one, as soon as I am ready with it. Thank you!

Comment: Edited the post and added an MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..has **html** content type .. Tabulations and spaces are gone.

Yes. That would do it.

**Unless** the relevant text were wrapped in `<pre>` and `</pre>` to indicate a **preformatted** section of text, the spaces are normalized and tabs ignored.

Comment: I wrapped the paragraphs in `<pre>` and `</pre>` as the following:
`<pre><p> content </p></pre>` it works fine in Mozzila, but not in the`JTextPane`. I also tried the `white-space:pre;` in the paragraph like this: `<style type="text/css"> 
p{ font-family: arial; font-size: 10; font-weight: bold; margin:0; white-space:pre;} 
 </style> `, it worked in Mozzila, but not in `JTextPane`. In the `JTextPane` a blank line appears only. What is the way of using `<pre>` tag in **java** `JTextPane` ? Appling the tags for only a part of the line results additional line breaks.

Comment: `<pre><p>` ..no.  Within a preformatted section, only spaces, tabs, characters/numbers/symbols and new lines are understood.  Once it gets into that section, it is the programmers responsibility to insert line breaks as needed.

Comment: `<pre>OFFLINE          </pre>` if I do this, my output will be this: 
http://postimg.org/image/djay68nx5/ . I use the following CSS style `pre{display:inline;}`, to prevent the additional breaks, but it has no effect. It break before and after the `pre` tags, and it removes the text's style too.